# UTC time format to milliseconds in PHP (local timezone issue)

Tags: php, datetime, utc

I am trying to get milliseconds from a date like this `2014-09-15T10:27:29Z`

I tried the following

```
return strtotime('2014-09-15T10:27:29Z');
```

But it returns a WARNING:

```
It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/New_York' for 'EST/-5.0/no DST'
```

So, I have to use the function `date_default_timezone_set`but not fixed to `'America/New_York'`:

```
$userZone = //I don't know what to put here
date_default_timezone_set($userZone);
return strtotime('2014-09-15T10:27:29Z');
```

How do I get the user timezone?

Comment: How do you want to get something which is not there?

Answer (score 0):

The Z on the end of the date/time string implies Zulu time, or [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#UTC) as it is more commonly known.

> The UTC time zone is sometimes denoted by the letter Z – a reference to the equivalent nautical time zone (GMT), which has been denoted by a Z since about 1950. The letter also refers to the "zone description" of zero hours, which has been used since 1920 (see time zone history). Since the NATO phonetic alphabet and amateur radio word for Z is "Zulu", UTC is sometimes known as Zulu time. This is especially true in aviation, where Zulu is the universal standard. This ensures all pilots regardless of location are using the same 24-hour clock, thus avoiding confusion when flying between time zones.

Comment: I know, but this time will be displayed differently in Tokio and New York. How do I display the proper time?

Comment: If you use [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects, instead of simple unix timestamps, you can easily display the date/time for whatever timezone you want